# How to tell if two hotel reviews addressing the same thing

Tags: natural-language-processing, text-generation

I am playing with a large dataset of hotel reviews, which contains both positive and negative reviews (the reviews are labeled). I want to use this dataset to perform textual style transfer - given a positive review, output a negative review which address the same thing. For example, if the positive review mentioned how spacious the rooms are, I want the output to be a review that complains about the small and claustrophobic rooms.

However, I don't have positive review-negative review pairs for the training. I was thinking that maybe I could create those pairs myself, but I'm not sure what is the best way to do that. Simple heuristics like jaccard index and such didn't give the desired results.

Comment: This seems like a tricky data set to create automatically. Do you have a different goal you want to eventually achieve, once you have this data set? Put differently, why are you building such a data set? By the way, "style transfer" can very often be equated with "translation" in NLP.

Comment: Well, my goal is to show that supervised style transfer can work in practice in complex cases, so I could get funds for labeling a very challenging dataset :)